# How to scale vector data in R using min/max?

Tags: r, vector, max, scaling, min

Imagine I have a vector of values in R. It's super long but just do give you a sample:

```
[1] 2782.779 2781.655 2780.531 2779.407 2778.282 2777.898 2777.514 
2777.130 2776.746 2776.471 2776.196 2775.921
[13] 2775.646 2775.055 2774.463 2773.872 2773.281 2774.238 2775.195 
2776.152 2777.109 2776.905 2776.701 2776.497
[25] 2776.293 2775.658 2775.024 2774.389 2773.755 2774.214 2774.673 
2775.132 2775.591 2777.585 2779.579 2781.574
[37] 2783.568 2787.358 2791.149 2794.940 2798.731 2802.518 2806.305 
2810.092 2813.879 2814.760 2815.641 2816.522
```

I want to scale/normalize each value in the vector so it ranges between 0 and 1. The `max` value of the dataset would take on a value of 1 and the `min` value would take on a value of 0. Are there any existing functions/libraries to easily implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that here, **normalized values = (value-min)/(max-min)**. So try this:

```
v1 <- 1:100
v2 <- (v1-min(v1))/(max(v1)-min(v1))
v2
```

or just `v2 <- scales::rescale(v1, to=c(0,1))`

Comment: Thanks! This is super easy and helpful!

Comment: I had never seen the `rescale` function before - thanks!